# md5sum fails on recived file from socket

Tags: c, sockets

I wrote simple client - server application using TCP socket to copy file from one machine to other machine.

Copying files on same machine succeed on verifying the md5sum of the files but same fails on copying to remote machine :(

### Local copy

$>my_copy file.tar.gz root@127.0.0.1:/home/viswesn/file.tar.gz

$>md5sum file.tar.gz
199b341684f528012e44dbf13512c5fc

$>md5sum /home/viswesn/file.tar.gz

199b341684f528012e44dbf13512c5fc

### Remote copy

$>my_copy file.tar.gz root@blrlapx12:/home/viswesn/file.tar.gz

$>md5sum file.tar.gz

199b341684f528012e44dbf13512c5fc

$>md5sim /home/viswesn/file.tar.gz

d4cbf92a9d2ed632e429c69334c6bf7a

### Code on Server side

```
int sendFile(int sock, FILE *fp, long int size) {
int rc = -1;
char dir[DIRSIZE + 1] = {'\0'};
long int nsend = 0;
int nread = DIRSIZE;
int wc = -1;
nleft = size;

while (!feof(fp)) {        
    rc = fread(dir, sizeof(char), nread, fp);        
    nsend += rc;        
    if (rc > 0) {
            printf("Sending %ld of %ld bytes\r", nsend, size);
            wc = write(sock, dir, rc);
            if (wc != rc) {
                    printf("failed to write to sock %d %s\n", sock, strerror(errno));
                    goto end;
            }
    }
    bzero(dir, rc + 1);        
}
printf("\n");
rc = 0;
end:
   if (sock) {
      close(sock);
   }
   return (rc);
}
```

### Code on Client Side

```
int getFile(int sock, char *filename, long int startOffSet, long int size) {
   char dir[DIRSIZE + 1] = {'\0'};
   int rc = -1;  
   FILE *fp = NULL;    
   int cnt = 0;
   int nread = DIRSIZE;
   long int nrecv = 0;
   int wc = 0;
   long int nleft = size;

   fp = fopen(filename, "w");
   if (fp == NULL) {
      printf("unable to open file %s %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
   } else {
      printf("open file %s success\n", filename);
   } 

   while(nleft > 0) {
    if (nleft < nread) {
        nread = nleft;
    }        
    cnt = read(sock, dir, nread);
    if (cnt <= 0) {
       goto end;
    }
    nleft -= cnt;
    nrecv += cnt;
    dir[cnt] = '\0';
    wc = write(fp, dir, cnt);
    if (wc != cnt) {
        printf("\nFailed to write to %d", fileno(fp));
        break;
    }        
    printf("Writing %d - [Recv : %ld] / [ Total : %ld] bytes\r", cnt, nrecv, size);
   }
   if (nrecv != size) {
       printf("\nFailed to get file data %ld/%ld - diff of %ld\n", nrecv, size, size - nrecv);
       goto end;
   }
   printf("\n");
   rc = 0;
  end:
     if (fp != NULL) {
         /* close descriptor for file that was sent */
         printf("Closing file descriptor %d\n", fileno(fp));
         fclose(fp);
    }
    return (rc);
  }
```

Comment: You might consider using [netcat](http://nc110.sourceforge.net/) (`nc`) instead of one of these ends in order to debug your program – or to replace your program.

Comment: I got this working :) . The issue is not in this piece of code but before calling this method I do send and recv which creates the issue. I find it by running strace and looked in to find the what I recv and send.

Answer (score 0):

For client you are opening file in text mode.

```
fp = fopen(filename, "w");
```

This could lead to issues if client and server are on OS that uses different end of line. For example Unix and Windows.
Try to open file in binary mode.

```
fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
```

If this doesn't help then compare files using for example kdiff3 and check where are a differences.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open file in binary mode `fopen(filename, "wb");` and don't forget do the same in on the client side.

Note: your code is require more strict error checking (fopen, fread, fwrite calls can fail) and some symmetric (why sendFile use `FILE *` as parameter when getFile open it by itself).